# data not save to mySQL Hosted DB

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-fragments, android-studio

i want to save this data from android app to mysql database in server. i make code with php.. when i run only php file data will be saved to db.. but it run form android application. data not save to DB.

**save code in android**

```
 public void loadSave() {
              String mydataurl = "http://xxxxxxxxxx/saveData.php";
          //String type = params[0];
         try {

        String longi = "aaa"; // Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        String lati = "aare";//Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        String user = "a";
        String lisence = "b";
        String date = "c";
        URL url = new URL(mydataurl);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("longi", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(longi, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                URLEncoder.encode("lati", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lati, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                URLEncoder.encode("lisence", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lisence, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                URLEncoder.encode("date", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(date, "UTF-8");
        bufferedWriter.write(mydataurl);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();
                } catch (MalformedInputException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**php code**

```
require "DB_Connection.php";

$longi =$_POST["longi"];
$lati = $_POST["lati"];
$user = $_POST["user"];
$lisence =$_POST["lisence"];
$date = $_POST["date"];

$query1="INSERT INTO mapdata (longi,lati,user,lisence,date)   
values ('".$longi."','".$lati."','".$user."','".$lisence."', '".$date."' )";

mysql_query($query1) or die ('Error :' . mysql_error());
```

**calling loadSave()**

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
            loadSave();
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: any error you get?

Comment: No error messages

this how i call that method 
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
                loadSave();
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();

Comment: try echo variables in `php` file. skip saving data for now.

Comment: try echo is working.. why this not working? any idea ?

Comment: Any idea  about this